# Simulating multiple modbus slave devices using node red

Tags: raspberry-pi, node-red, modbus

I've managed to simulate a single slave device on my raspberry pi using node-red using functions to send data random values to the Modbus flex server. However, now I want to be able to simulate multiple Modbus slave devices on the port number and I'm unsure how to do this.

I've tried creating another Modbus flex server with the same port number, but this causes the whole node-red application to crash when it's deployed. Secondly, I've tried using different Modbus flex-write nodes to simulate different slave devices, but I'm unsure whether this is correct and if so, how I'd configure them to appear as different slave devices. This is because so far, my raspberry pi appears as slave 1, but I'm unsure where this comes from. I'm guessing it's to do with the unit-id of the Modbus flex-server but when I change the unit-id to a different number and type that number as the address in the master, it says no connection.

In conclusion, is it possible to use a single raspberry pi to simulate multiple slave devices on node-red using node-red-contrib-modbus and if so how do you do it?

Answer (score 0):

The concept of Slaves in Modbus TCP differ somewhat from RTP as set out in the [Modbus TCP Spec](http://www.modbus.org/docs/Modbus_Messaging_Implementation_Guide_V1_0b.pdf):

> The MODBUS ‘slave address’ field usually used on MODBUS Serial Line is
>   replaced by a single byte ‘Unit Identifier’ within the MBAP Header.
>   The ‘Unit Identifier’ is used to communicate via devices such as
>   bridges, routers and gateways that use a single IP address to support
>   multiple independent MODBUS end units.

So there is a difference in termanalogy between Modbus RTP and TCP as well as a difference in the intended use of this field. The solution suggested by the spec would be to setup multiple servers on different ports (you cannot run multiple servers on a single port).

Having said that some TCP->RTP gateways (and other devices) use the unitid as the slave ID so I'm assuming you are trying to simulate something like this?

The first issue is that there appears to be a bug in `Modbus Flex Server` ([reported](https://github.com/BiancoRoyal/node-red-contrib-modbus/issues/172)) in that when you change the unit-id it is being stored as a string rather than a number. If you export the flow you will see something like `"unitId": "3",`; changing this to `"unitId": 3,` (no quotes around the 3) and importing fixes the issue (so that probably explains why you could not get this working).

Having said that changing the `unit-id` like this does not help you because it only supports one ID. However if you set the `unit-id` to 255 then it will listen on all unit-ids (this is a feature of the [modbus-serial](https://github.com/yaacov/node-modbus-serial) module used internally). Remember that you will currently need to manually fix the config to get this to work due to the bug.

Having done that you can do something like the following to respond to requests to different unit ids (the example will return the unit id (1 or 2) for all addresses so is not useful but shows the concept):

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works. I'm slightly confused about why the Modbus flex server has to have a Modbus flex read node for it to work though. Not a big deal.

Comment: Why can't I access global variables in the 'get holdings' tab? Instead of returning one each time the master requests to view unit 1, I'm trying to return a global variable that is set elsewhere in the code. The code I've used to set the variable is "global.set("num",msg.payload). Then I'm trying to access it in the modbus flex server using `if (unitID === 1) {  value1 = global.get(min.h); return value1;` This causes the master to respond saying "read output register failed". How am I actually meant to access variables in this function so I can set the value elsewhere?

Comment: "Why the Modbus flex server has to have a Modbus flex read node for it to work" - It doesn't (my testing was with the flex server node only)

Comment: "Why can't I access global variables in the 'get holdings' tab?" - The flexserver node runs the scripts in a vm and does not appear to provide access to globals (you can use ```node.warn(this);``` to see what is available). Simplest workaround would be to set the values via modbus calls (otherwise you would need to request a change to the node).

Comment: What do you mean when you say modbus calls? Currently, I can set one unitID by using a function node with the code `msg.payload = { 'value' : msg.payload, 'register' : 'holding', 'address' : 0, ' disablemsg': 0 <br/> }; return msg` but this only sets the address that corresponds to the unitID of the flex server node. When I try and change the address from 0 and try and view the value in that address the master returns "read output register failed: slave device or server failure". Do you mean using the modbus write nodes? If so please provide an example, as I don't really understand them.

Comment: Yes - I meant using the modbus write nodes (and changing the handlers for the write functions). I don't know if this would actually work but seems the simplest approach. An alternative is to change the node itself - adding access to the global context [somewhere around here](https://github.com/BiancoRoyal/node-red-contrib-modbus/blob/master/src/modbus-flex-server.js#L68) might work). The demos show how the write notes work fairly well (the flex-server demo has write nodes changing the values in a flex-server). Sorry this is not something I have time to investigate in more depth.

Comment: Note: the approach also depends upon your requirements. If you just want each node to return the same value for each coil/register (no need for writes) on each call then just hardcode the values in the settings (e.g. have something like ```let unitID1Registers = [0,9999,343,2223,332,...]``` and then ```if(unitID===1){return unitID1Registers[addr]}```). The node does not really support what you are trying to achieve so you may need to get creative...

Comment: Hello, I am trying to do the same but it has not worked, I cannot emulate different slaves on a single server and port. I have checked Github to see if I found a solution but it is not resolved there either: [link](https://github.com/BiancoRoyal/node-red-contrib-modbus/issues/351) (I will reopen it to see if there is any luck).
Were you able to resolve it?